# Not able to receive file from client in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to program compilation server which compiles a C program sent by client and returns an object file which can then be linked and executed at the client. Here are my client and server programs respectively

client.py:

```
# Compilation client program

import sys, socket, string


File = raw_input("Enter the file name:") 
ssock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock.connect(('localhost', 5000))

csock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
csock.connect(('localhost', 5001))

f = open(File, "rb")
data = f.read()
f.close()
ssock.send(File)                 #send filename
ssock.send(data)                 #send file
fd=raw_input("Enter a key to start recieving object file:") 

data=csock.recv(1024)            #receive status
if data=="sucess\n":
    File=File.replace(".c",".o") #objectfile name
    print "Object file, "+File+", recieved sucessfully"
else:
    print "There are compilation errors in " + File
    File="error.txt"             #errorfile name
    print "Errors are reported in the file error.txt"

fobj=open(File,"wb")
while 1:
    data=ssock.recv(1024)        # if any error in c sourcefile then  error gets                                         
                                 # eported in errorfile "error.txt" else objectfile is 
                                 # returned from server
    if not data:break
    fobj.write(data)
fobj.close()
ssock.close()
csock.close()
```

---

server.py

```
#Compilation Server program

import subprocess
import socket, time, string, sys, urlparse, os
ssock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock.bind(('', 5000))                   
ssock.listen(2)
print 'Server Listening on port 5000'
csock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
csock.bind(('', 5001))
csock.listen(2)
print 'Control server listening on port 5001'
client, claddr = ssock.accept()
controlsoc, caddr = csock.accept()


filename=client.recv(1024)        #receive filename
print filename
###############  This code is not working, i'm not getting the reason   #######
###############    I want to receive a file more than 1KB from client   #######
f = open(filename,"wb")           #receive file======
while 1:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    f.write(data)
f.close()
###############
###############


data="gcc -c " + filename + " 2> error.txt"  #shell command to execute c source file 
                                             #report errors if any to error.txt    
from subprocess import call

call(data,shell=True)                        #executes the above shell command
fil = filename.replace(".c",".o")
if (os.path.isfile(fil))== True:             #test for existence of objectfile 
    data = "sucess\n"                        #no objectfile => error in compilation
    filename = filename.replace(".c",".o")
else:
    data = "unsucessful\n"
    print data+"hi"
    filename = "error.txt"

controlsoc.send(data)
f = open(filename,"rb")
data=f.read()
f.close()
print data

client.send(data)

client.close()
controlsoc.close()
```

---

I'm not able to recieve files of multiple KB. Is there any flaw in my code or how should i modify my code in order to achieve my objective of coding a compilation server.
Please help me with this regard..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you assume that `ssock.send(File)` will result in `filename=client.recv(1024)` reading exactly the filename and not more, but in fact the receiving side has no idea where the filename ends and you end up getting the file name *and* part of the data in the `filename` variable.

TCP connection is a *bi-directional stream of bytes*. It doesn't know about boundaries of your messages. One `send` might correspond to more then one `recv` on the other side (and the other way around). You need an *application-level protocol* on top of raw TCP.

The easiest in your case would be to send a text line in the form `file-size file-name\n` as a header. This way your server would be able to not only separate header from file data (via newline) but also know how many bytes of file content to expect, and reuse same TCP connection for multiple files.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after modifying it as you said